# Docker Auto update volume after mounting disk to it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, docker-volume

I have a volume mount that mounts my `/media` directory to the container.  It sees the mount points that exist there, but can only see the contents of them if the disk is mounted before the container is started.  If a drive is disconnected then reconnected, or was connected after the container has started, it can't view the contents.

How can I make it so that it automatically updates the volume mount when I mount a drive on the host?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement for mounts is that your host folder must exist when starting the container.

I think your problem is due to your `/media` in host disappear when you unmount. So, if the container doesn't find volume folder, it loses reference.
The only thing I can recommend you is:

- Create folder /media in host.
- Mount your fs in /media/...
- Build docker image where /media doesn't exist.
- Create container sharing /media volume.

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: The mount point exists before it's mounted (I created it preemptively and mount by putting it in the fstab).  But the contents go away when it's not mounted.

Comment: Have you checked that /media doesn't exist in container? If it exists inside it, volume cannot be mounted: it preseves data in contaner, not from outside